# Cannot serialize dates with ksoap2

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, ksoap2

No matter what format I try, I can't send a date from my Android (Java) app to the .NET web service. I've tried sending it as a `GregorianCalendar`, a `Date`, a `Calendar`... Nothing works.

I get a "cannot be serialized" error as a runtime exception. I'm using ksoap2 to manage my web service calls. Any ideas?

Errors below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: java.util.GregorianCalendar...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: java.util.Date...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to track this down eventually through several dead ends. It seems the ksoap library doesn't know what to do with dates or doubles to be sent through on the webservice call - you need to tell it how to handle them or it gets a serialization error.

The way to do this is to implement the `MarshalDate` class: [this tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html) has the code you need to implement it.

From my experiences, ksoap2 has the `MarshalDate` class already in the library and that class will do the job, but doesn't register it against the envelope by default. By registering it against the envelope (as below), the problem was resolved. For doubles or other floating point numbers, use `MarshalFloat` instead.

To fix this problem, before you send your `SoapSerializationEnvelope` through your `HttpTransport` make this call:

```
new MarshalDate().register(envelope);
```

where `envelope` is your `SoapSerializationEnvelope`.

I found out the ksoap2 library has the `MarshalDate` and `MarshallFloat` classes by accident when importing the class, as Eclipse provided me with two options for importing it - one of which was within ksoap2. The included class sufficed and I removed my custom one.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer please? I can't tell from what you've written in it whether the MarshalDate class inside KSOAP2 is enough to solve this issue (and registering it against the envelope of course)

Comment: Yes, the MarshalDate class inside KSOAP2 is enough to solve the issue, but it may need to be added for KSOAP.

Comment: Hmmm I'm using the latest version of KSOAP2, but still getting "Cannot serialize: java.util.GregorianCalendar"

Comment: @Jose_GD, you've registered the `MarshalDate` class to your envelope? If so, try using the tutorial to make your own within your package and register that instead.

Comment: I've registered it, I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Checking my own code, I'm sending up my datetime as a Date object. It's possible that other Date object types may have problems.

Comment: Yes @yoda, I confirm this: Date works, other date types such as GregorianCalendar, no. And I didn't need a separate MarshalDate class. Thanks for your time