# Error when using KSOAP2 in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-studio

I am a newbie in android and I have a problem when I try parsing JSON  from .NET webservices to load this data to listview.

[Here is my webservices](http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx)

[Here is JSON:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8izj.png)

Here is MainActivity:

```
private EditText departure;
private EditText arrival;
private EditText date;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList;
private ArrayList<TicketInforModel> ticketInforModelArrayList;
private TicketInforModel ticketInforModel;
private ArrayAdapter<TicketInforModel> arrAdapterTicket;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_ticket_main);

    departure = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_departure);
    arrival = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_arrival);
    date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_date);


    Button btn_searching = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_searching);
    btn_searching.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}

public class JSonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<JSONObject>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<JSONObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<JSONObject> listJSon=new ArrayList<>();
        String TAG_SOAPACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/searchingTickets";
        String TAG_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String TAG_METHODNAME = "searchingTickets";
        String TAG_URL = "http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx";
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(TAG_NAMESPACE, TAG_METHODNAME);
        request.addProperty("date", date.getText());
        request.addProperty("departure",departure.getText());
        request.addProperty("arrival",arrival.getText());
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transport=new HttpTransportSE(TAG_URL);
        try{
            transport.call(TAG_SOAPACTION1,envelope);
            SoapPrimitive data= (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String jsonText=data.toString();
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonText);
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                listJSon.add(jsonObject);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return listJSon;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONObject> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(result);
    }
}

public void arrAdapter() throws JSONException {
    String TAG_IDTICKET = "ID_Ticket";
    String TAG_Company = "Company";
    String TAG_Departure = "Departure";
    String TAG_Arrival = "Arrival";
    String TAG_VEHICLESTYPE = "Vehicles_type";
    String TAG_SERVICES = "Services";
    String TAG_Date = "Date";
    String TAG_Time = "Time";
    String TAG_Price = "Price";
    String TAG_TicketStatus = "Ticket_Status";
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        ticketInforModel = new TicketInforModel();
        ticketInforModel.set_IdTicket(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_IDTICKET).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_company(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Company).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_departure(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Departure).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_arrival(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Arrival).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_vehicletype(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_VEHICLESTYPE).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_services(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_SERVICES).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_date(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Date).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_time(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Time).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_price(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Price).toString()));
        ticketInforModel.set_ticket_Status(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_TicketStatus).toString());
        ticketInforModelArrayList.add(ticketInforModel);
    }
}

public void loadDataToListView() throws JSONException {
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_ticket);
    arrAdapterTicket = new viewListTicket();
    listView.setAdapter(arrAdapterTicket);
}

class viewListTicket extends ArrayAdapter<TicketInforModel>{
    viewListTicket(){
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.ticket_design,ticketInforModelArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ticket_design, parent, false);
        }
        TicketInforModel currentTicket = ticketInforModelArrayList.get(position);
        TextView tv_time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        tv_time.setText(currentTicket.get_time());

        TextView tv_company = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_company);
        tv_company.setText(currentTicket.get_company());

        TextView tv_phone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        tv_phone.setText("1111");

        TextView tv_price= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_price.setText(((Double.toString(currentTicket.get_price())) ));

        TextView tv_service= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_services);
        tv_service.setText(currentTicket.get_services());

        return itemView;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is TicketInforModelL:

```
public TicketInforModel(String IDticket, String Company, String Departure, String Arrival, String Vehicletype, String Services, String Date, String Time, double Price, String Ticket_status){
    this.set_IdTicket(IDticket);
    this.set_company(Company);
    this.set_departure(Departure);
    this.set_arrival(Arrival);
    this.set_vehicletype(Vehicletype);
    this.set_services(Services);
    this.set_date(Date);
    this.set_time(Time);
    this.set_price(Price);
    this.set_ticket_Status(Ticket_status);
}
public TicketInforModel(){

}


public String get_company() {
    return _company;
}

public void set_company(String _company) {
    this._company = _company;
}

public String get_departure() {
    return _departure;
}

public void set_departure(String _departure) {
    this._departure = _departure;
}

public String get_arrival() {
    return _arrival;
}

public void set_arrival(String _arrival) {
    this._arrival = _arrival;
}

public String get_vehicletype() {
    return _vehicletype;
}

public void set_vehicletype(String _vehicletype) {
    this._vehicletype = _vehicletype;
}

public String get_services() {
    return _services;
}

public void set_services(String _services) {
    this._services = _services;
}

public String get_date() {
    return _date;
}

public void set_date(String _date) {
    this._date = _date;
}

public String get_time() {
    return _time;
}

public void set_time(String _time) {
    this._time = _time;
}

public double get_price() {
    return _price;
}

public void set_price(double _price) {
    this._price = _price;
}

public String get_ticket_Status() {
    return _ticket_Status;
}

public void set_ticket_Status(String _ticket_Status) {
    this._ticket_Status = _ticket_Status;
}

public String get_IdTicket() {
    return _IdTicket;
}

public void set_IdTicket(String _IdTicket) {
    this._IdTicket = _IdTicket;
}
```

When I debug this app. The for loop can not end. So I think I wrong something when I get arrayObject. But I don't know what are wrong. Anyone please show me what i was wrong and solution for this problem. Thanks you.
p/s: My english is not good, so sorry if i use wrong grammar.

Comment: Can you paste your json as text ?

Comment: so sorry about that, I have resolved it. The loop can not be end because  I have wrong with serialize dates. I found this wrong is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368631/cannot-serialize-dates-with-ksoap2 I'm trying do it as tutorial but it not working. So any idea for wrong can not serialize dates?